# Plotting dates on x axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, datetime, formatting

I have a list of dates:

```
x = ['20200116, '20200117']
```

which i want to plot on x-axis. I used below code for formatting the list:

```
x = (datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for date in x)
```

Expected output : a list with dates in '%m/%d/%Y' format but it returns an object.
What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `x` variable is a generator object, either use `list(x)` or `[...]` instead of `(...)`.